# Adding comment disables content control toggling with spacebar

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a Word macro that checks the validity of a series of checkbox content controls that the user selects. The checkboxes are grouped into yes-no pairs. Currently, if the user tabs through both checkboxes in the pair without checking either, a comment appears on the side.

For example, my document looks like this:

```
Was an interpreter used?
    yes[ ] no[ ] 
If yes, was the interpreter understood?
    yes[ ] no[ ]
```

If the user tabs through both yes and no in the first question without changing the value of either to `[x]` then a comment is added to a bookmark around `"Was an interpreter used?"` saying something like `"Please check one of the following:"`

The validity of the checkbox group is checked on each triggering of the `Document_ContentControlOnExit` event. Usually, the user can change whether a checkbox is checked by pressing the spacebar.

The problem is that when the comment is added the spacebar stops allowing the user to toggle the next checkbox. For example, if I have the `no[ ]` box selected in the first question and I press tab, a comment is added to `Was an interpreter used?` and the focus shifts to `yes[ ]` in the next question. However now if the user presses the spacebar then `yes[ ]` in the second question does not become checked. I can still tab through the checkboxes and the spacebar functionality returns as soon as I have tabbed out of `yes[ ]`. The line I am currently using to add the comment is:

```
Set myComment = TempDoc.Comments.Add(TempDoc.Bookmarks(Bookmark).Range, Text)
```

The line simply adds a new comment to a pre-defined bookmark alerting the user of the mistake. I am almost positive that this is the line that causes the spacebar to stop working, since when I comment it out everything works fine.

How can I get the spacebar to toggle the next checkbox after I add my comment?

Comment: Is the focus being moved to the comment when you create it, or is it staying with the checkbox?

Comment: Does Comments.Add set the focus on the new comment? I will check that out.

Comment: I had a chance to double-check and it doesn't look like the focus moves to the comment normally, so that's probably not it. How are you capturing the tab and spacebar keypresses? I work with dialogs a lot more than I do with content controls, so I'm not sure what, if any functionality is built-in vs. written into the code.

Comment: Normally the spacebar automatically toggles the checkbox from check to unchecked. When I try to capture the spacebar with .keybinding it doesn't seem to work either while I am in a checkbox! Does that happen with anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact mechanism that is causing this, but it seems to me that after you create the comment Word is selecting the next text box at a different 'level' than it would otherwise. I created a very basic version of what I think you're doing, and what I see when I tab from a group of checkboxes that do require a comment is subtly different from what I see when I tab from a group of checkboxes that do not require a comment.

[image] [image]

What seemed to fix it was adding a line after the line that adds the comment:

```
Selection.End = Selection.Start
```

This seems to force the checkbox's selection state back to what is required for the spacebar to work. Hopefully that will work for you. There does not seem to be an abundance of documentation of this Word feature online.